# Split text file into smaller ones by bytes in python

Tags: python-3.x, text

I have a problem with splitting a large text file into smaller files by the size (in bytes) 
e.g. text file has 30kB, I want to split it into multiple files with 5kB each.

I search a lot but I found almost ways split the file by lines.

any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are looking into splitting it into files of uniform size (e.g. 5KB each), then one solution would be:

1. Read the large file as binary
2. For every 5000 bytes (5KB), create a new file
3. Write those 5000 bytes into the new file

Sample code:

```
i = 0
with open("large-file", "r", encoding="utf8") as in_file:
    bytes = in_file.read(5000) # read 5000 bytes
    while bytes:
        with open("out-file-" + str(i), 'w', encoding="utf8") as output:
            output.write(bytes)
        bytes = in_file.read(5000) # read another 5000 bytes
        i += 1
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, but it doesn't work fine with Unicode texts.

Comment: may I ask in what way does it not working? is it the reading or the writing part?

Comment: in writing part, when I read segmented files, it views unreadable characters.

Comment: can you paste some of the characters here? it might be an issue with the encoding

Comment: ط§ظ„ط¥ط¹ظ„ط§ظ† ظ…ط¤ط®ط±ظ‹ط§طŒ ط¹ظ† ظ†ظٹط© ط§ظ„ط¯ط®ظˆظ„ ظپظٹ ط§ط³طھط«ظ…ط§ط± ظ…ط´طھط±ظƒ ظپظٹ ظ…طµظپط§ط© ظƒط¨ظٹط±ط© ط§ظ„ط­ط¬ظ… ط¨ط§ظ„ط³ط§ط­ظ„ ط§ظ„ط؛ط±ط¨ظٹ ظ„ظ„ظ‡ظ†ط¯".
ظˆظ‚ط§ظ„ ط§ظ„ظ…ظ‡ظ†ط¯ط³ ط§ظ„ظ†ط§طµط± ط¥ظ† "ط£ط±ط§ظ…ظƒظˆ ط§ظ„ط³ط¹ظˆط¯ظٹط© طھطھظˆط³ط¹ ظپظٹ ط£ط¹ظ…

Comment: yes it works fine but I add encoding parameter, open (file, 'r', encoding="utf8"), also for writing

Comment: How would you prevent a line from being split before going to the next file? Say you had XYZ values and one line was half written in one file and the rest of the line in the next?